# Command failed: heroku login

Tags: django, git, heroku

Начал изучать Django. По ссылке глава на которой застрял: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment.
Проблема в том, что при выполнении команды 'heroku create' получаю ошибку:

```
D:\Programming\Gits\LocalLib>heroku create
   Creating app... !
   !     Invalid credentials provided.
   heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
   Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/cli/browser/f28188c8-5bb9-48f8-9e1d- 
   fc4c3d4f33b5?requestor=SFMyNTY.g2gDbQAAAAw3OS4xMDUuNzQuMzZuBgBugmEqeAFiAAFRgA.06IK1OTdqz- 
   kkK4FN7ozNGW2avpDmjr3yaFTcVgNzIs
   Logging in... done
   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Z:/_netrc'
   !    Command failed: heroku login
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет требуемого файла по пути:

```
Z:/_netrc
```

Comment: Спасибо. Нашёл ответ в этой ветке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760769/heroku-cli-login-is-failing-with-error-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory/62267567#62267567